# It is possible to add php to this script in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I use this script to filter posts from single category. I based on tags which generate also a class. It is possible to generate this script by WordPress with all tags from my site?
For example below 2 scripts (now I have 12 scripts of this type):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr').show();
  $("#aipa").click(function(){
    $("tr").show();
    $('tr:not(:first)').not(".aipa").slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr').show();
  $("#ris").click(function(){
    $("tr").show();
    $('tr:not(:first)').not(".ris").slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Now when I add new tags I must manually add another script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr').show();
  $("#next-tag").click(function(){
    $("tr").show();
    $('tr:not(:first)').not("#next-tag").slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: Exactly! But I don't know if it's possible, that WordPress generate jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this. This assumes that you're using the standard blog tag system, and that your variable you're using as your ID and class is the tag's slug. Alter it as needed for your needs.

```
<?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
        $('tr').show();
        $("#<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>").click(function(){
            $("tr").show();
            $('tr:not(:first)').not(".<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>").slideToggle('fast');
        });
    <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

This will create a single document ready function, and then generate multiple click functions.